# Using bibtex in Lyx can't get hyphen between some numbers

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx

I'm totally new to all this.

Here is my BibTex source from Jabref

{`@Article{Butt,
  author   = {Butt, H.J. and Cappella, B. and Kappl, M.},
  title    = {Force measurements with the atomic force microscope: Technique, interpretation and applications},
  journal  = {Surface Science Reports},
  year     = {2005},
  volume   = {59},
  number   = {1–-6},
  pages    = {1 - 152},
  doi      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.surfrep.2005.08.003},
  issn     = {0167-5729},
  keywords = {Atomic force microscope, Force curves, Surface forces },
  url      = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167572905000488},
}`

I copied this from a downloadable .bib file the hyphen shows correctly in the 'pages' part but not the volume part. (initially it was just (-) I changed it to (--) after looking around but it didn't really help, I also tried ( - ) like in the pages part.

This is how it outputs

H.J. Butt, B. Cappella, and M. Kappl. Force measurements
with the atomic force microscope: Technique, interpretation
and applications. Surface Science Reports,
59(1â-6):1 - 152, 2005.

(actually before adding the double hyphen I just got â so adding the double hyphen did get a hyphen to appear but didn't get rid of the â)

This is the LaTeX error description that shows in LyX:

> ...lock {\em Surface Science Reports}, 59(1â€
>                                                     “-6):1 -- 152, 2005.
>   You need to provide a definition with \DeclareInputText 
>   or \DeclareInputMath before using this key. Blockquote

I'm not sure where or how I would put these definitions so haven't tried.

The same thing is happening with this BibTex source too

{`@Article{Gross,
  author  = {Leo Gross},
  title   = {Recent advances in submolecular resolution with scanning probe microscopy},
  journal = {Nature Chemistry},
  year    = {2011},
  volume  = {3},
  pages   = {273–-278},
}`
In the pages section.

Thanks.

If it matters I was using natbib but changed it to default, no help.

Comment: are you using bibtex or biber, something is generating utf8 but tex is apparently expecting latin1 so any multi-byte utf8 character is being garbled and coming out with nonsense starting with accented a (usual sign of mis-interpreted utf-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two `-` if using the `--` ligature,

For example your:

```
{273–-278},
```

is

```
  U+007b LEFT CURLY BRACKET     &lcub; &lbrace; \lbrace
  U+0032 DIGIT TWO     2
  U+0037 DIGIT SEVEN     7
  U+0033 DIGIT THREE     3
  U+2013 EN DASH     &ndash; \textendash
  U+002d HYPHEN-MINUS     -
  U+0032 DIGIT TWO     2
  U+0037 DIGIT SEVEN     7
  U+0038 DIGIT EIGHT     8
  U+007d RIGHT CURLY BRACKET     &rcub; &rbrace; \rbrace
```

Note the first dash is U+2013 not U+002D  (–not-)

Comment: Wow. That is remarkable I didn't even notice the difference. How do I specify which dash I want I just hit the dash on my keyboard and have now fixed the issue using copy and paste.

Comment: @J.B92 no idea about your keyboard mapping, that's editor and operating system specific so not really tex related, also I wasn't clear how far back in the workflow the en-dash is in the file, in the input to jabref? or its output (I've never used jabref:-)

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll just save a copy ready to be pasted.